# Examples of Lurie tensor product computations

Tags: higher-category-theory, infinity-categories, derived-algebraic-geometry, higher-algebra

I am interested in examples of computing the Lurie tensor product.

For example, if $A$ and $B$ are connective DG algebras (over $\mathbb{Z}$, say), then I think there is an equivalence $A\text{-mod} \otimes B\text{-mod} \simeq (A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B)\text{-mod}$; how could one prove this?

I have some underived intuition for why this should be true: $A\text{-mod} \otimes B\text{-mod}$ corresponds to $\operatorname{Funct}_{cnt}((A\text{-mod}^{op}, B\text{-mod})$, the category of colimit-preserving functors $A\text{-mod}^{op} \to B\text{-mod}$, and any such functor is determined by where it sends $A \in A\text{-mod}$; moreover, the image of $A$ will have compatible $B$-module and an $\operatorname{End}_{A\text{-mod}}(A)$-module structures. Since the latter algebra identifies with $A^{op}$, we get an $(A^{op},B)$-bimodule, which is the same as an $A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B$-module. However, I have no idea how to prove this in the $\infty$-categorical (or DG) setting.

In a similar vein, how would we deduce from this that for arbitrary DG schemes (over a characteristic zero field $k$ now) $X \to Y \leftarrow Z$, there is an equivalence $\operatorname{QCoh}(X \times_Y Z) \simeq \operatorname{QCoh}(X) \otimes_{\operatorname{QCoh}(Y)} \operatorname{QCoh}(Z)$? Any relevant ideas to these or other computations would be appreciated!

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/0805.0157v5, Theorem 4.7 has a version of this.

Comment: This is HA.4.8.5.16. (And yes, the rough heuristic is correct: it boils down to the classification of colimit preserving functors between module categories in terms of bimodules.) The claim about quasi-coherent sheaves is also true, and can be deduced from this by comparing to O_X-modules, I think.

Comment: sorry, the claim about QCoh requires more hypotheses than I thought (but I think are satisfied for qcqs schemes): SAG 9.4.2.3

Comment: $Mod_A\otimes Mod_B$ should be $Mod_{A\otimes_\mathbb S B}$, not $A\otimes_\mathbb Z B$. HA 4.8.5.16 implies this version, as $Sp\otimes Sp \simeq Sp$, but $Mod_\mathbb Z\otimes Mod_\mathbb Z\not\simeq Mod_\mathbb Z$. If you take tensor product *over* $Mod_\mathbb Z$, then you do get what you want